# Why does the while loop stop before the else statement?

Tags: c

I want to execute the outputs that are in else statements (True or Nothing) but for some reason, my while loop only executes either first if statement or else if. I know that I am using infinite loop but I want to leave it by using break function that is in one of the two of else statements. What I want is to execute the else statements, so, Do they have hair? ->Y -> Messi? -> Y-> True. Or Do they have hair -> N -> Beckham? -> Y -> True. Or Do they have hair -> N -> Beckham ->N ->Nothing. Or Do they have hair -> T->Messi->N-> Nothing

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>



int random(char z[]);


int main() {

    char *x ="Do they have hair";
    char *yes = "Messi";
    char *no = "Beckham";
    char *u ="Nope";


    do {
        char *currents = x;
        while (1) {
            if (random(currents)) {
                if (yes) {
                    currents = yes;
                    printf("First check\n");
                } else {
                    printf("True: %s\n", yes);
                    break;
                }

            } else if (no) {
                currents = no;
                printf("False\n");

            } else {
                printf("Nothing\n");
                break;
            }
        }
    }while(random("Run Again?"));
    return 0;
}
int random(char z[])
{
    char a[3];
    printf("%s: %s",z,a);
    fgets(a, 3,stdin);

    return a[0] == 'y';
}
```

Comment: Your `yes` and `no` variables are non-null pointers, so their truth value is always true (since they are never changed in the loop body).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `while` loop is not be quit because `if (yes)` and `if(no)` are always `true`.

`yes` is `Messi`. All non-zero value is referenced as `true`.
So, Your `yes` value has always the address of memory where `Messi` is saved. and It's always non-zero.
`no` is also same. `no` is always pointing on `Beckham`. So, It's `true`

So, I modified the code for your logic. Please refer the following code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int random(char z[]);
int main() {

    char x[] = "Do they have hair";
    char again[] = "run again";
    char yes[] = "Messi";
    char no[] = "Beckham";
    char u[] = "Nope";

    do {
        if (random(x)) {
            if (random(yes)) printf("True!\n");
            else printf("Nothing!\n");
        }
        else {
            if (random(no)) printf("True!\n");
            else printf("Nothing!\n");
        }
    } while (random(again));
    return 0;
}
int random(char z[])
{
    char a[3];
    printf("%s?:", z);
    fgets(a, 3, stdin);

    return a[0] == 'y';
}
```

Comment: What I want is to execute the else statements, so, Do they have hair? ->Y -> Messi? -> Y-> True. Or Do they have hair -> N -> Beckham? -> Y -> True. Or Do they have hair -> N -> Beckham ->N ->Nothing. Or Do they have hair -> T->Messi->N-> Nothing